# How can I return normal sidebar after building Jupyter-lab after installing an extension?

Tags: jupyter-lab, tableofcontents

I'm trying to install [TOC](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-toc) extension for Jupyter lab.

The issue is the same for for both ways of installation: from command window or from extension manager.

1) I'm installing an extension using command:

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/toc
```

2) Then I have to build Jupyter lab using:

```
jupyter lab build
```

3) Icons from sidebar disappearing like in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856540/sidebar-disappearing-jupyter-lab). Here is [the screen](https://send.firefox.com/download/23573845b32a5038/#0nq-I4uhAR2KWlnJ26tw1w).

And I can not return to normal view unless I reinstall Anaconda. What can I do for correct work? Or at list how can I return to correct build of Jupyter Lab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest upgrading to the latest version of Jupyterlab. I was having a similar error as mentioned here https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/7158 and the problem has disappeared after I upgrade from 1.0.2 (as per anaconda package) to 1.1.2.

Good luck and I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed:
`pip install --upgrade jupyterlab`